# How to completely reinstall mysql?

Tags: mysql

when trying to do apt-get upgrade i got the following error:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: Zeile 143: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: file not found
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends of mysql-server-5.7; but:
  Paket mysql-server-5.7 isn't configured.
```

(roughly translated from german)

I don't know what that is, but i figured i could solve it by simply reinstalling mysql. That didn't worked. So i followed the instructions of all the other questions in this StackExchange to purge everything mysql related and reinstall it anew. Still the same error.

How to do a complete reinstall of mysql? This seems like there is always some old data somewhere.

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade`. If that does not work, try removing the mysql packages: `sudo apt remove mysql-server mysql-server-5.7` and then upgrading and then installing the mysql stuff again after upgrading.

Comment: I already tried that. Same error.

Comment: Describe more precisely what happened then. If you removed the packages successfully, then there should not be any error messages related to those packages when you try to upgrade. I suggest that you update your post with more detailed info about what you have tried and precisely what the error messages were for each thing you tried. If you give more info, you increase the chances that someone can help.

Comment: I don't know why it matters. I purged it from my system and then tried to reinstall it but the error happened again. Shouldn't, but it does. This has nothing to do with upgrades. It's something inside the mysql package thats fucked up or some leftover data.